# Prove that $\frac{n!}{\pi^n}\geq n\;; n\geq 9$.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I found that the following inequality 
$$\frac{n!}{\pi^n}\geq n,$$
holds for all integers such that $n\geq 9$. Also I know that $\frac{n!}{\pi^n}$ is greater than $n$ from a number on. So I arrived at this via putting $n=1$ to $n=9$.
But I could not how to prove that.It is equivalent to prove $\frac{(n-1)!}{\pi^n}\geq 1\;; n\geq 9$.  Any hint can help me. Thanks.

Comment: Did you mean "equivalent to prove $\frac{(n-1)!}{\pi^n} \ge 1$"?

Comment: @ automaticallyGenerated, yes, you are right.

Comment: Have you tried induction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**. Try induction step $P(n) \Rightarrow P(n+1)$
$$\frac{n!}{\pi^n}\geq n \Rightarrow \frac{(n+1)!}{\pi^n}\geq n(n+1)\geq\pi(n+1) \Rightarrow
\frac{(n+1)!}{\pi^{n+1}}\geq n+1$$

Initianl step $P(n_0)$ for $n_0=9$ you already covered. For more details [see this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction#Induction_basis_other_than_0_or_1).

Comment: @ rtybase what happen for $n=1$ to $n=8$?

Comment: You need an initial $n_0$ for which $P(n_0)$ is true, which you found already, $n_0=9$.

Comment: @ rtybase that is right.

Comment: As a remark, initial induction step doesn't have to start with $n_0=0$ or $n_0=1$. You need one starting point.